# Custom Timer Job is not working in production

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-jobs

I have a document library called Documents in production. I wrote a timer job for sending emails based on the columns in the library.

Everything was fine in the dev environment but the timer job in prod is giving me exceptions. Any ideas?

[image]

`

```
public void SendCorporateReminder(SPWeb web)
    {
        SPList lstComplaint = Helper.GetList(web, "Documents", Helper.ListType.Library);

        if (lstComplaint != null)
        {
            string query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='DocFormat' /><Value Type='Choice'>Policy</Value></Eq></Where>";
            SPListItemCollection colRecords = Helper.ExecuteQueryRecursive(lstComplaint, query, null, 2000);

            if (colRecords != null && colRecords.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (SPListItem item in colRecords)
                {

                    DateTime Expires = Helper.GetSPFieldDateTimeValue(item, "Expires");
                    String Title = Helper.GetSPFieldTextValue(item, "Title");
                    SPFieldUserValueCollection userResp = Helper.GetUsers(item, "Contact");
                    TimeSpan totaldays = DateTime.Now.Date - Expires.Date;
                    Int32 days = totaldays.Days;
                    String emailtemplatekeyA = "AEmail" + days.ToString();
                    String emailtemplatekeyB = "BEmail" + days.ToString();
                    String respToEmail = String.Empty;


                    if (userResp != null && userResp.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (SPFieldUserValue user in userResp)
                        {
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(respToEmail))
                                respToEmail += ",";
                            respToEmail += user.User.Email;
                        }
                    }
                    HandleEmails handleEmail = new HandleEmails();
                    handleEmail.AddValueToPlaceholder(HandleEmails.EmailPlaceHolders.SendingTypeValue.EmailRecipient, PlaceHolder.USERRESP.ToString(), respToEmail);
                    handleEmail.AddValueToPlaceholder(HandleEmails.EmailPlaceHolders.SendingTypeValue.OTHER, PlaceHolder.TITLE.ToString(), Title);
                    handleEmail.AddValueToPlaceholder(HandleEmails.EmailPlaceHolders.SendingTypeValue.OTHER, PlaceHolder.EXPDT.ToString(), Expires.ToShortDateString());
                    handleEmail.AddValueToPlaceholder(HandleEmails.EmailPlaceHolders.SendingTypeValue.OTHER, PlaceHolder.ID.ToString(), item.ID.ToString());
                    handleEmail.SendMail(web, emailtemplatekeyA);
                    handleEmail = new HandleEmails();
                    handleEmail.AddValueToPlaceholder(HandleEmails.EmailPlaceHolders.SendingTypeValue.EmailRecipient, PlaceHolder.USERRESP.ToString(), respToEmail);
                    handleEmail.AddValueToPlaceholder(HandleEmails.EmailPlaceHolders.SendingTypeValue.OTHER, PlaceHolder.TITLE.ToString(), Title);
                    handleEmail.AddValueToPlaceholder(HandleEmails.EmailPlaceHolders.SendingTypeValue.OTHER, PlaceHolder.EXPDT.ToString(), Expires.ToShortDateString());
                    handleEmail.AddValueToPlaceholder(HandleEmails.EmailPlaceHolders.SendingTypeValue.OTHER, PlaceHolder.ID.ToString(), item.ID.ToString());
                    handleEmail.SendMail(web, emailtemplatekeyB);
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Can you share full exception messgae?

Comment: The stack trace only shows us where the exception occurred.  What is the actual exception and error message?

Comment: 1)The Execute method of job definition CorporatePoliciesTimerJob.DailySchedule (ID 6a9e19a2-4141-47a7-b879-3ce10653b614) threw an exception. More information is included below.  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job Corporate Policies - Reminder Emails). Execution Time=593.354392806907

Comment: This is the execute method in DailySchedule class         public override void Execute(Guid contentDbId)
        {
           
            string siteURL = this.Properties["siteurl"].ToString();
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteURL))
            {
              using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())            
                {
                    DailyPoliciesReminder dailyrem = new DailyPoliciesReminder();
                    dailyrem.SendCorporateReminder(web);
                }
            }

Comment: did you see more error regarding this in ULS logs, may be filter by correlation id.

Comment: If you look at the stack trace, you can see that the exception is actually thrown from SendCorporateReminder().  So that means something in SendCorporateReminder is null.  Did you change the "siteurl" property in production to reflect the correct URL for production?  If not, when you try to open the site and web, you may be trying to open using the URL of your dev environment, which would result in the site and web being null.

Comment: Also, just as a suggestion, if you post more information requested by the commenters (like the error message, or more of your code), you should edit your question and add it there in a code block.  It would provide better readability than posting code in the comments.

Comment: I copied wsp file from dev and pasted in 14 hive. I deployed using CA in prod (globally). i opened site collection features and activated the feature. Anything wrong in this process?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dyalna. This is my first time asking a question here.

Comment: see above foe SendCorporateReminder method code.

Comment: Regarding your deployment process, the only thing I can see that might be wrong is going back to the idea of the "siteurl" properties.  In the beginning of your Execute function you are getting a URL from `this.Properties["siteurl"].ToString()`. Where and when is that property set?  Are you sure it is set to the URL of the production site?

Comment: am getting siteurl from project properties. But in dev i am giving dev site . after i deploy to development environment uccesfully i am not chaning anything in the code(including url), am coping wsp from dev and pasting in prod and deploying in prod globally. AM creating a "EmailTemplate" list in prod also.

Comment: What do you mean by "project properties"?  In the context of the Execute method on a timer job, `this.Properties` refers to a property bag stored on the timer job definition.  In order for `this.Properties["siteurl"]` to have a value, you would need to set it in code somewhere.  Do you do this in your feature activation code?

Comment: am getting from site url property. After it is deployed successfully in dev am changing the site url property and builting a package and deploying in prod.

Comment: I think I understand.  You are saying you set the timer job's "siteurl" property by reading from your VS project's Site URL property?  Where in your code do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue and resolved it. Person whose userid is no longer valid is Contact person of a document (he is in contact column for the library I am creating timer job).

So timer job is throwing exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) whenever it is trying to read Contact column of the document. I figured it out by modifying my code as below and I removed that person from that column. That user exists in dev server so the timer job is worked in dev but not in prod. Anyhow, issue is resolved in prod now.

```
Helper.WriteUlsInformation("Item processing:" + i.ToString(), TraceSeverity.Verbose);
DateTime Expires = Helper.GetSPFieldDateTimeValue(item, "Expires");
Helper.WriteUlsInformation("Expires:" + Expires.ToString(), TraceSeverity.Verbose);
String Title = Helper.GetSPFieldTextValue(item, "Title");
Helper.WriteUlsInformation("Title:" + Title, TraceSeverity.Verbose);
SPFieldUserValueCollection userResp = Helper.GetUsers(item, "Contact");
Helper.WriteUlsInformation("UserResp read" , TraceSeverity.Verbose);
TimeSpan totaldays = DateTime.Now.Date - Expires.Date;
Int32 days = totaldays.Days;
Helper.WriteUlsInformation("Days:"+ days.ToString(), TraceSeverity.Verbose);
String emailtemplatekeyA = "AEmail" + days.ToString();
String emailtemplatekeyB = "BEmail" + days.ToString();
String respToEmail = String.Empty;
```